# How can I cross compile only 1 subproject in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project sbt build using Build.scala.

I want to cross-compile one subproject against Scala 2.12 and 2.11, but the other subprojects have dependencies that don't support 2.12 yet, so I just want 2.11.

How can I do this in sbt?

I've tried this:

```
val scalaVer = "2.11.8"
val scalaVer12  = "2.12.0"

lazy val basicSettings = Seq(
    scalaVersion                := scalaVer
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .aggregate(scalajack, scalajack_dynamodb, scalajack_mongo)

lazy val scalajack = project.in(file("core"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(Seq(crossScalaVersions := Seq(scalaVer, scalaVer12)))

lazy val scalajack_dynamodb = project.in(file("dynamodb"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .dependsOn( scalajack )

lazy val scalajack_mongo = project.in(file("mongo"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .dependsOn( scalajack )
```

This will build everything correctly but ignores my wish to have a 2.12 version of 'core' subproject.

I build packages with:

```
sbt> + package
```

Comment: I'm such not an expert on this, but I very suspect you need https://github.com/sbt/sbt-doge. Wow.